# How to clip and draw a picture approximately?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl, pst-grad

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-text,pstricks-add,pst-grad}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(10,5)
\psframe*[fillstyle=solid,opacity=.5](-5,-5)(10,5)
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,linewidth=4.5pt,linejoin=2}
\pnodes(5;100){A}(5;160){B}(5;-55){C}(0,0){O}
\pstCGravABC{A}{B}{C}{G}
\pstTriangleIC[linestyle=none]{A}{B}{C}
\pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none]{B}{A}{C}{A'}
\pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none]{A}{C}{B}{C'}
\pstInterLL[PointSymbol=square]{A}{A'}{C}{C'}{I}
\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
\pstInterLL{A}{I}{M}{O}{E}
\psline[linecolor=red!50](O)(E)(A)(M)
\cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](IC_O){I'}{\textbf{I}}
\cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](G){G'}{\textbf{G}}
\cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](O){O'}{\textbf{O}}
%%%
\definecolor{ColorM}{hsb}{0.99999, 1, 1}
\definecolor{ColorN}{hsb}{0, 0, 1}
\pspolygon[linewidth=7pt,gradbegin=ColorM,gradend=ColorN](A)(B)(C) %% !?
\pscircle(0,0){5}
%%%%
\psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red!50!orange,gradend=yellow!70,gradangle=50}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{1.7cm}
\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
    \rput(3.25,2.75){\RM Iranian}}%      (3.25,2.75)!?
\end{pscharclip}
\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
    \rput(4.5,1.2){\RM Geometry}}%       (4.5,1.2)!?
\end{pscharclip}
\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
    \rput(5,-.25){\RM Olympiad}}%   (5,-.25)!?
\end{pscharclip}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The official image:

https://igo-official.ir/static/intro/images/logo.png

Question:

1. The gradient can be used for `line` ?
2. As the image ouput, I see the circle of I is smaller than G and O? How to fix?
3. See ***`!?`*** in the image output, how to delete the extra white space?
4. How to clip *`the part of content`* inside circle (I tried but it is failed.) and arrange it evenly?(See the official image)
5. I don't have the knowledge about `font`, so can anyone tell me know?

(Yes, not drawing exactly, only need approximately)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-text,pstricks-add,pst-grad}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{1.7cm}%
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5.2,-5.2)(10,5.2)
\psframe*[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black!40,opacity=.9](-5.2,-5.2)(10,5.2)
\pscircle*[dimen=inner](0,0){5}
{%
    \psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!15,linecolor=black!15}%
    \rput[lb](0.5,-1){\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
        \RM\tabular[t]{l}Iranian\\~Geometry\\~~Olympiad\endtabular}
    \end{pscharclip}}%
}
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,linewidth=4.5pt,linejoin=2}%
    \pnodes(5;100){A}(5;160){B}(5;-55){C}(0,0){O}
    \pstCGravABC{A}{B}{C}{G}%
    \pstTriangleIC[linestyle=none]{A}{B}{C}
    \pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none]{B}{A}{C}{A'}
    \pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none]{A}{C}{B}{C'}
    \pstInterLL[PointSymbol=square]{A}{A'}{C}{C'}{I}
    \pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
    \pstInterLL{A}{I}{M}{O}{E}
    \psline[linecolor=red!50](O)(E)(A)(M)
    \cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](IC_O){I'}{\textbf{I}}
    \cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](G){G'}{\textbf{G}}
    \cnodeput[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50](O){O'}{\textbf{O}}
    %%%
    \definecolor{ColorM}{hsb}{0.99999, 1, 1}%
    \definecolor{ColorN}{hsb}{0, 0, 1}%
    \pspolygon[linewidth=7pt,gradbegin=ColorM,gradend=ColorN,linecolor=black!20](A)(B)(C)
    \psclip{\pscircle[dimen=inner,linestyle=none](0,0){5}}
      \psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red!50!orange,gradend=yellow!70,gradangle=50}%
      \rput[lb](0.5,-1){\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
         \RM\tabular[t]{l}Iranian\\~Geometry\\~~Olympiad\endtabular}
      \end{pscharclip}}%
      \pscircle[dimen=inner,linecolor=red!40,fillstyle=none](0,0){5}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

`\end{pscharclip}` needs a `%` at the end.
For the circle use `dimen=inner`. You can Times or Helvetica as font. The rest can be done by yourself ...

[image]

Why is the radius of I smaller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{1.7cm}%
\newsavebox\CBox
\begin{document}
\begin {tabular}{llll}
& width & height & depth \\\hline
I \global\sbox\CBox{\RM I} & \the\wd\CBox & \the\ht\CBox & \the\dp\CBox\\

G \global\sbox\CBox{\RM G} & \the\wd\CBox & \the\ht\CBox & \the\dp\CBox\\

O \global\sbox\CBox{\RM O} & \the\wd\CBox & \the\ht\CBox & \the\dp\CBox\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For I we need at least a diameter of 33,33 pt, but for G and O we need at least a diameter of 37,63 pt ...

for identical circle radius:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](5,2)
    \Cnodeput[radius=5mm](1,1){Left}{foo\vphantom{g}}% to get the same height
    \Cnodeput[radius=5mm](4,1){Right}{right}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Colors/colors#contColor and for IGO use `\vphantom{IGO}I`, `\vphantom{IGO}G`, ... Then all radii are the same

Comment: I tried with `\vphantom{IGO}I`,`\vphantom{IGO}G`, but it is unchanged. You can check. See edited question.

Comment: my mistake: `\vphantom` doesn't work here. Use a node macro which allows to define a radius.

Comment: `radius` is also unchanged....

Comment: Please to check `radius` macro for `\cnodeput` ...

Comment: What shoulkd I check?? See edited answer. I wrote that you should use a macro which allows to set the radius! `\cnodeput` doesn't!